# DCC32 command-line compiler completes successfully, but does not generate the EXE file

Tags: delphi, dcc32

I'm using the Delphi 5 command-line compiler to do a build. The build does not report any errors, however it does not generate the EXE file either.

I can confirm the following:

- Doing the same build via the IDE behaves correctly.
- There is no difference in the source code or options between IDE vs. DCC32 build.
- The problem occurrs only on a full build. I.e. doing a build first with -B option and followed by one without, the 'compile' correctly generates the EXE file.
- Using the -E switch on the command-line to force an invalid build output path doesn't report an error -- as if there isn't even an attempt to generate the EXE file.
- Other projects do build correctly.
- I have disabled anti-virus software and so can confirm that that is not the problem.

---

EDIT
Although I experienced this with Delphi 5, it is not specific to that version. The [Delphi Bug List](http://buglist.jrsoftware.org/generated/entry0625.htm) confirmed the issue in at least D4-D6.

Comment: What version of windows, what sp level, and what A/V sofware do you have?  Disabling A/V is not even going to fix it, with some brands of A/V software, they would have to be completely removed without a trace, before I would trust that it was not breaking your apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lengthy investigation, I've managed pinpoint the problem.

- I wrote a little batch file to do the build and check for the EXE and report success or failure either way.
- I then went through the painstaking process of eliminating dependencies one at a time and retesting the build.
- I eventually tracked it down to a specific compiler directive `{$ObjExportAll ON}` that was used in some of our third party packages.
- Searching the internet revealed that this bug was introduced when the $ObjExportAll was added for BCB support. Though it seems to have been rarely encountered - just my luck :(
- I'm unsure if or which version the bug was fixed.

You can test the bug with the following simple project:

```
program TestDCC32ObjExportAll;

{$OBJEXPORTALL ON}

begin
end;
```

- With the directive, dcc32 does not create the EXE.
- Without the directive, dcc32 *does* create the EXE.
- The IDE always creates the EXE.

Fortunately we don't use BCB at all, so I've simply disabled the directive wherever it occurred.

---

EDIT
The wonderful resource [The Delphi Bug List](http://buglist.jrsoftware.org/generated/entry0625.htm) reports that the issue was confirmed to exist in Delphi 4, 5, and 6. Unfortunately, The Delphi Bug List was discontinued after that. :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use ProcessMonitor by SysInternale/Microsoft to investigate on `.exe`creation. Run `procmon.exe` and add filter with "Path" "contains" (your exe name) then "include".

In my environment compiling `t.pas` gave:

```
    12:09:58,1927245    DCC32.EXE   3596    CreateFile  C:\tmp\t.exe    SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OverwriteIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Overwritten
    12:09:58,1928116    DCC32.EXE   3596    CreateFile  C:\tmp\t.exe    SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Complete If Oplocked, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
    12:09:58,1928281    DCC32.EXE   3596    QueryFileInternalInformationFile    C:\tmp\t.exe    SUCCESS IndexNumber: 0x46b00000000c296
    12:09:58,1928376    DCC32.EXE   3596    CloseFile   C:\tmp\t.exe    SUCCESS 
    12:09:58,1961352    DCC32.EXE   3596    WriteFile   C:\tmp\t.exe    SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 19 968
    ....
```

Maybe it is bug in `dcc32`?

Comment: +1, but it's not a bug in dcc32. I've used the command line compiler in every version of Delphi since v1 was released, and never run across this issue. A bug this bad would have been reported a long time ago. This is a configuration issue of some kind (in the .cfg file or command-line options or something), and ProcMon should help figure out what's going on.

Comment: +1 Very useful information, although it doesn't really tell me anything new. It just confirms what I suspected in any case - dcc32 isn't even attempting to write the EXE file.

Comment: @Ken: Careful now, that sort of thinking is what leads to many a wasted hour down the wrong rabbit hole because the right hole was ignored due to false logic. ;)  I did indicate that other projects did build correctly, so the bug in dcc32 does require some other special condition to be met. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I remember similar things with somewhere in the Delphi 5 era (might be Delphi 4 or Delphi 6 though) in the IDE when we had some rogue .dcu file (which we did have a a .pas file).

Deleting the .DCU files before building resolved the issue.

Also: anti-virus software can do really bad timing-related things to your system; been there done that: most of my development systems are in a virtual machine without anti-virus for that reason alone.

Try to reproduce your Delphi 5 dcc32 issue on a clean machine (just Windows and the Delphi components you need, nothing more).

If that works, then use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see the differences between those machines as Michał Niklas suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a very known issue (for those, who works with D5).

For example, FinalBuilder contains "Use workaround for Delphi 5 compiler bug" in "Build Delphi project" action, which builds project twice with different options - specifically to create exe, when dcc32 doesn't create one (according to help file).

There is no similar option for Delphi 4 or Delphi 6, so I guess that it was introduced in Delphi 5 and was fixed in Delphi 6.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Yes, one workaround is to build (generating all the DCU's) then compile. However, The Delphi Bug List does report the issue as being confirmed in D4-D6. I updated my answer to indicate as such.